# Create jar from an android project

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to make some changes to existing project and then generate jar for the project: https://github.com/loopj/android-smart-image-view

Is it possible to generate jar from this kind of project? I tried adding this project as an android project in eclipse but it cannot recognize it as an android project.

Comment: the quick and dirty version would be, create a new android project and copy the java files int it, or just copy the java files to your current project in a new package

Comment: create a new library project then replace the src folder with the one in that git

Comment: Yes u can generate jar from this project.. This is an ANT project, that's why ADT does not recognize it as android project. You should create New project from existing code.

Comment: Download and extract project, adjust files and build it through terminal using the ANT build system (build.xml). You cannot import it as an Android project because it is not an Android project (standard java project with attached android.jar)

Comment: I created new project, added the src folder from project and generated the jar. I then added this jar to my existing android project but I cannot access the files from the generated jar.

Answer (score 2):

Convert **Android Project** to **Android Library Project**. Build Project. You will get JAR of Android Library Project in bin folder of same app.

Eclipse converts ***Android Library Project*** to ***JAR*** using ***ANT***.

[image]

Comment: May be way is incorrect but you will definitely get JAR from this way.